# HTML img is not changing its size

Tags: php, html, css

i have this HTML line here (its an echo from php)

```
echo "
<div class='rowItem'>
    <div class='singleItem'>
        <div class='itemImage' >
            <img src= $arr3[$i] >
        </div>
        <div class='itemName'>$arr1[$i]</div>
        <div class='itemPrice'><br> Php$arr2[$i]
            <div class='orderButtonDiv'>
                <a href='menu_burger.php'>ORDER</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>";
```

Here is the CSS I'm using

```
.itemImage{
  height:100%;
  width :100%;
}

.itemImage img{
  width: 60%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.itemName{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.itemPrice{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin-left: 41%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  z-index -1;
}

.singleItem{
  width: 48%;
  background-color: #e0dede;
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

here picture of the result

[image]

as you can see i am not able to resize the image here is the css code. Aside from that it is also overlapping some text

here is the image without the picture without the image

[image]

How can i resize the image properly that it will follow the the height of single item and at the same time equate its width to its height

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a div with

```
  background:url([imagepath]);background-size:cover;
```

is the best solution, the css property:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Can help if you want to preseve the img aproach, but is less backwards compatible.
As for the overlaping text, read the documentation for z-index css property.

Comment: object fit doesn't do anything unfortunately. tried your first suggestion and change it to this: <div class='itemImage' style='background-image:url($arr3[$i]);background-size:cover;'> </div> . Image is gone now :/

Comment: are you sure the output is correct? mean $arr3[$i] has a correct image url?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the image in the question it did show the pictures, so i can say that it is the correct url

Comment: could it be possible i have something wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply the background-image as an inline style. You can then add background-size: cover; onto .singleItem in css to control the background image size.

```
    .itemImage{
      height:100%;
      width :100%;
    }

    .itemImage img{
      width: 60%;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }

    .itemName{
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
      font-size: 150%;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-left: 40%;
      margin-top: 4%;
    }

    .itemPrice{
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
      font-size: 110%;
      margin-left: 41%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 25%;
      z-index -1;
    }

    .singleItem{
      width: 48%;
      background-color: #e0dede;
      background-size: cover;

      border:1px solid red;
      height: 150px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

---

```
echo "
<div class='rowItem'>
  <div class='singleItem' style='background-image: url(\"{$arr3[$i]}\");'>

      <div class='itemName'> {$arr1[$i]}
      </div>

      <div class='itemPrice'><br> Php{$arr2[$i]}
          <div class='orderButtonDiv'><a href='menu_burger.php'>ORDER</a></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>";
```